# Adding function to calculate "best" row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like:

```
    Letter    freq       dollars   
0   a         1          421
1   b         3          32 
2   c         2          97.4
3   d         0          -40
4   e         9          3214
```

For a given row, my score function could be something like `score = freq * log(dollars)`.

**How do I get the row (Letter, freq, dollars) with the top score? Follow-up, is there a way to get the top n rows sorted by the score?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['score'] = df.freq *  np.log(df.dollars).fillna(0)
df.sort_values(by='score', ascending=False)

    Letter  freq    dollars score
4   e       9       3214.0  72.677444
1   b       3       32.0    10.397208
2   c       2       97.4    9.157652
0   a       1       421.0   6.042633
3   d       0       -40.0   0.000000
```